# How to delete and replace multiple lines in Python when executing the code in command prompt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

```
for j in range(len(output),0,-1):
    for i in range(6000):
        print("="*int(len(output)/2),"OUTPUT","="*int(len(output)/2),"\n"," "*3,output[:j],''.join(random.choice(L2) for _ in range(j))," "*3,"\n","="*(((len(output)//2)*2)+6),sep="")
        clear(3)
```

Edit: 'output' in the above code is just a string, the '=' signs appear on the basis of the length of the output.
I want to remove the three lines that show up.
For example:

```
=====OUTPUT=====
   Output1234
================
```

Such that at first, the output inside is just a bunch of random strings changing quickly but slowly the output appears. I do already know about \r but that doesn't work with replacing 3 lines. I have tried using escape sequences but I don't know if it's because of my python version(3.9.6) or because I am using command prompt, it just doesn't work. I have figured out how to clear the whole screen

```
def clear():
    os.system('clear' if os.name =='posix' else 'cls')
```

but not only is that very slow but also breaks the 'animation'. Also, for an example of the 'animation' I am trying to achieve try running the following code:

```
import random
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(10000):
        print("OUTPUT12"[0:i+1],end='')
        print(''.join(random.choice('qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm1234567890') for _ in range(7-i)),end="\r")
```

Lastly, for more info on me trying to use escape sequences, most of them just tend to show arrows that don't replace the text as I want them to. I tried using

> \033c(which gave ←c),\033[F(which gave ←[F),\033[A(which gave ←[A)

This means \033 just gives the arrow I guess, I am not really sure.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, I guess replacing only 2 lines would also work as I want the animation inside the "======"s, so the first one doesn't need to be replaced.

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example, for now too many variables are missing

Comment: @mozway Sorry about that but the second example of the animation just works without any variables and what I want exactly is "===OUTPUT===" and "============" above and below it. To run the first code just make output="AnyString". It is a little confusing because the "=" signs appear based on the length of the output and the "6000" in the loop is just to have sufficient time to reveal each letter.